# EMQx Mqtt Broker WSS web socket connection failed , I am using Letsencrypt SSL Certbot

Tags: websocket, mqtt, lets-encrypt, certbot, emq

OS: ubuntu 16.04

my emqx.conf file

```
listener.wss.external.certfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomainname.com/cert.pem
listener.wss.external.cacertfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomainname.com/chain.pem

listener.wss.external.verify = verify_none
listener.wss.external.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
```

Can somebody post detailed link on how to.

I am using MQTT broker **v3.2.1**

Please help me,

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try the `fullchain.pem` file instead of the `chain.pem` for the ca certs

Answer (score 0):

try

```
listener.wss.external.keyfile = privkey.pem
listener.wss.external.certfile = fullchain.pem
```